# Property 'originalUrl' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

My project is a typescript project which uses a gulpfile to start.
In the gulpfile I use express where I try to access `req.originalUrl` where req is the request object

It throws the error `Property 'originalUrl' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.`

I have tried the following with no avail:

1. Add typeRoots to tsconfig and custom typings in /src/types/express/index.d.ts
2. Install @types/express-serve-static-core

I have noticed that using `req['originalUrl']` but I am not supposed to change this file.

Below is my package json:

```
"dependencies": {

        "@types/express-serve-static-core": "^4.17.31",

        "@types/fs-extra": "^8.0.1",

        "@types/gulp": "^4.0.6",

        "@types/node": "^13.13.48",

        "@types/sass": "^1.16.0",

        "cors": "^2.8.5",

        "express": "^4.17.1",

        "express-http-proxy": "^1.6.2",

        "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",

        "gulp": "^4.0.2",

        "jest": "^26.4.0",

        "mustache": "^4.2.0",

        "portfinder": "^1.0.28",

        "sass": "^1.32.8",

        "ts-node": "^8.6.2",

        "typescript": "^3.9.9"

    },

    "devDependencies": {

        "@types/express": "^4.17.11",

        "@types/express-http-proxy": "^1.6.1",

        "@types/jest": "^26.0.22",

        "@types/jsdom": "^16.2.9",

        "@types/mocha": "^8.2.2"

    }
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the package version of typescript

Using `"typescript": "^4.6.4",` works